# Rewrite to https for all URLs

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect to https for ALL URLs hitting my site.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, accessing http://www.example.com is not redirecting. I'd like a request to `http://www.example.com` to redirect to `https://www.example.com`

It seems my rule is having no effect. Is the condition possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example:More look at [**Rewrite URLs on an HTTPS page to HTTP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165440/rewrite-urls-on-an-https-page-to-http)

```
<rule name="ForceHttpToHttps" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
<match filterByTags="A, Img" pattern="^(?!.*javascript).*$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="ON" />
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" value="https://{HTTP_HOST}:1860{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: That resulted in a "HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error." and loads of unknown tags in the XML.